# Need to extend credit-card-type.js for master card detection and add new/latest regex pattern(resolved by myself)

Tags: php, magento-2.1, payment-methods, magento-2.1.3, regex

Need to extend credit-card-type.js for add master card detection new/latest pattern:

I am creating and extending payment method using this link http://inchoo.net/magento-2/implementing-payment-gateway-magento-2/

Its working fine ... **just not detecting master card type until I put all 16 digit of the credit card** this is the problem i am facing

As of my understanding and research magento making credit-card-type.js at below path:

\pub\static\frontend\Magento\luma\en_US\Magento_Payment\js\model\credit-card-validation\credit-card-number-validator\credit-card-type.js

need to override this for add/update new pattern for master card detection like below link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72801/3820040

Checking if anyone have the resolution of the issue... 
Please let me know if you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing some research and development I found below solution/way to override js file:

Just go to `requirejs-config.js` file at below path... If you dont find then create the file. `[Namespace]/[Module]/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` and

add below code:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Payment/js/model/credit-card-validation/credit-card-number-validator/credit-card-type':'[Namespace]_[Module]/js/model/credit-card-validation/credit-card-number-validator/credit-card-type',               
        }
    }
};
```

Before this above code first take/copy credit-card-type.js file from below path:

```
\pub\static\frontend\Magento\luma\en_US\Magento_Payment\js\model\credit-card-validation\credit-card-number-validator\credit-card-type.js
```

and pase at your module js file location at

```
[Namespace]_[Module]/js/model/credit-card-validation/credit-card-number-validator/credit-card-type.js
```

Then you can make your custom changes as like I have done in my case.